# Function runs even though it is false

Tags: flutter

I have this code:

```dart
ValueNotifier<int?> idData = ValueNotifier<int?>(null);
  Future<void> updateData() async {
    ToolDataState dataForState = await ToolDataState.getState();
    ToolDataIndicator dataForIndicator = await ToolDataIndicator.getIndicator();
    List<Damage> dataForId = await Damage.getDamage();
    List<Damage> dataForMsg = await Damage.getDamage();
    setState(() {
      stateData = dataForState;
      indicatorData = dataForIndicator;
      idData.value = dataForId[dataForId.length - 1].id;
      msgData = dataForMsg[dataForMsg.length - 1].msg;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    const oneSec = Duration(milliseconds: 900);
    Timer.periodic(oneSec, (Timer t) => updateData());
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      stateData = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as ToolDataState;
      indicatorData =
          ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as ToolDataIndicator;
    });
    idData.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        run = true;
        isDamageIDNew = true;
      });
      overheatCheck();
    });
  }
```

```dart
  bool run = false;
     oilTempText() {
    return ValueListenableBuilder(
      valueListenable: idData,
      builder: (BuildContext context, value, Widget? child) {
        return Flexible(
            child: Container(
                height: 60,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                      colors: [
                        Color.fromRGBO(10, 25, 123, 0.5),
                        Color.fromRGBO(200, 200, 200, 0.5),
                      ],
                      begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      end: Alignment.centerRight,
                    ),
                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                      Radius.circular(20.0),
                    ),
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                        color: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.2),
                        spreadRadius: 4,
                        blurRadius: 7,
                        offset: Offset(0, 3),
                      )
                    ]),
                child: TextButton.icon(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.airplanemode_active),
                  label: Expanded(
                      child: run &&
                                  stateData.oil != 'null' &&
                                  msgData == 'Oil overheated' ||
                              msgData == 'Engine overheated'
                          ? BlinkText(
                              'Oil Temp= ${stateData.oil} degrees  ',
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 27,
                                  letterSpacing: 2,
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              endColor: Colors.red,
                              times: 10,
                              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                            )
                          : stateData.oil != 'null' || stateData.oil != null
                              ? Text('Oil Temp= ${stateData.oil} degrees  ',
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 27,
                                      letterSpacing: 2,
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))
                              : Text('No data  ',
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 27,
                                      letterSpacing: 2,
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
                  onPressed: () {},
                )));
      },
    );
  }
```

The issue is that the first condition in my `oilTempText()` function runs even though not all conditions are true, like stateData.oil is null but it shouldn't be (My Text widget shows null degrees, which should not happen)
It also runs the BlinkText only once and doesn't rerun when there is a new value for idData.

1. How can I make my conditions work properly? (SOLVED)
2. How can I make by `ValueListenableBuilder` rebuild the widgets when there is a new value available for idData?

The home state build method is here:

```
  oilTempText() {
    if (run && stateData.oil != 'null' && msgData == 'Oil overheated' ||
        msgData == 'Engine overheated') {
      return ValueListenableBuilder(
        valueListenable: idData,
        builder: (BuildContext context, value, Widget? child) {
          return Flexible(
              child: Container(
                  height: 60,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      gradient: LinearGradient(
                        colors: [
                          Color.fromRGBO(10, 25, 123, 0.5),
                          Color.fromRGBO(200, 200, 200, 0.5),
                        ],
                        begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        end: Alignment.centerRight,
                      ),
                      borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                        Radius.circular(20.0),
                      ),
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.2),
                          spreadRadius: 4,
                          blurRadius: 7,
                          offset: Offset(0, 3),
                        )
                      ]),
                  child: TextButton.icon(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.airplanemode_active),
                    label: Expanded(
                      child: msgData == 'Oil overheated' ||
                              msgData == 'Engine overheated'
                          ? BlinkText(
                              'Oil Temp= ${stateData.oil} degrees  ',
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 27,
                                  letterSpacing: 2,
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              endColor: Colors.red,
                              times: 10,
                              duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                            )
                          : Text('Oil Temp= ${stateData.oil} degrees  ',
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 27,
                                  letterSpacing: 2,
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  )));
        },
      );
    } else if (stateData.oil == 'null' ||
        stateData.oil == '15' ||
        stateData.oil == null) {
      return Flexible(
          child: Container(
              height: 60,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                    colors: [
                      Color.fromRGBO(10, 25, 123, 0.5),
                      Color.fromRGBO(200, 200, 200, 0.5),
                    ],
                    begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    end: Alignment.centerRight,
                  ),
                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                    Radius.circular(20.0),
                  ),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.red.withOpacity(0.2),
                      spreadRadius: 4,
                      blurRadius: 7,
                      offset: Offset(0, 3),
                    )
                  ]),
              child: TextButton.icon(
                icon: Icon(Icons.airplanemode_active),
                label: Expanded(
                  child: Text(
                    'No Data  ',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 27,
                        letterSpacing: 2,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ),
                onPressed: () {},
              )));
    }
  }

  late dynamic stateData;
  late dynamic indicatorData;
  late dynamic msgData;
  bool isNotifOn = true;
  bool isDamageIDNew = false;
  bool run = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Stack(fit: StackFit.expand, children: <Widget>[
        ImageFiltered(
          imageFilter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 7.0, sigmaY: 7.0),
          child: Image.asset(
            "assets/event_korean_war.jpg",
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        Stack(
          children: [
            Scaffold(
              backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
              resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
              appBar: AppBar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                  centerTitle: true,
                  title: indicatorData.name != 'NULL'
                      ? Text("You're flying ${indicatorData.name}")
                      : Text("No vehicle data available / Not flying!")),
              body: Center(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: [
                        Flexible(
                          child: Container(
                              height: 60,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                                    colors: [
                                      Color.fromRGBO(10, 25, 123, 0.5),
                                      Color.fromRGBO(200, 200, 200, 0.5),
                                    ],
                                    begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                    end: Alignment.centerRight,
                                  ),
                                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                    Radius.circular(20.0),
                                  ),
                                  boxShadow: [
                                    BoxShadow(
                                      color: Colors.pink.withOpacity(0.2),
                                      spreadRadius: 4,
                                      blurRadius: 10,
                                      offset: Offset(0, 3),
                                    )
                                  ]),
                              child: stateData.height != 'null'
                                  ? TextButton.icon(
                                      icon: Icon(Icons.height),
                                      onPressed: () {},
                                      label: Expanded(
                                        child: Text(
                                          'Altitude: ${stateData.height} meters ',
                                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 27,
                                              letterSpacing: 2,
                                              color: Colors.black,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  : TextButton.icon(
                                      icon: Icon(Icons.height),
                                      onPressed: () {},
                                      label: Expanded(
                                        child: Text(
                                          'No data available ',
                                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 27,
                                              letterSpacing: 2,
                                              color: Colors.black,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    )),
                        ),
                        Flexible(
                          child: Container(
                              height: 60,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                                    colors: [
                                      Color.fromRGBO(10, 25, 123, 0.5),
                                      Color.fromRGBO(200, 200, 200, 0.5),
                                    ],
                                    begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                    end: Alignment.centerRight,
                                  ),
                                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                    Radius.circular(20.0),
                                  ),
                                  boxShadow: [
                                    BoxShadow(
                                      color: Colors.pink.withOpacity(0.2),
                                      spreadRadius: 4,
                                      blurRadius: 10,
                                      offset: Offset(0, 3),
                                    )
                                  ]),
                              child: indicatorData.throttle == 'nul' ||
                                      indicatorData.throttle == '0'
                                  ? TextButton.icon(
                                      icon: Icon(Icons.speed),
                                      onPressed: () {},
                                      label: Expanded(
                                        child: Text(
                                          'Stationary/ Engine dead / No data!  ',
                                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 27,
                                              letterSpacing: 2,
                                              color: Colors.black,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  : TextButton.icon(
                                      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_upward),
                                      onPressed: () {},
                                      label: Expanded(
                                        child: Text(
                                          'Throttle = ${(double.parse(indicatorData.throttle) * 100).toStringAsFixed(0)}%',
                                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 27,
                                              letterSpacing: 2,
                                              color: Colors.black,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    )),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        iasText(),
                        Flexible(
                          child: Container(
                              height: 60,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                                    colors: [
                                      Color.fromRGBO(10, 25, 123, 0.5),
                                      Color.fromRGBO(200, 200, 200, 0.5),
                                    ],
                                    begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                    end: Alignment.centerRight,
                                  ),
                                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                    Radius.circular(20.0),
                                  ),
                                  boxShadow: [
                                    BoxShadow(
                                      color: Colors.pink.withOpacity(0.2),
                                      spreadRadius: 4,
                                      blurRadius: 10,
                                      offset: Offset(0, 3),
                                    )
                                  ]),
                              child: indicatorData.compass == '0' ||
                                      indicatorData.compass == null
                                  ? TextButton.icon(
                                      icon: Icon(Icons.gps_fixed),
                                      onPressed: () {},
                                      label: Expanded(
                                        child: Text(
                                          'No data  ',
                                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 27,
                                              letterSpacing: 2,
                                              color: Colors.black,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  : TextButton.icon(
                                      icon: Icon(Icons.gps_fixed),
                                      onPressed: () {},
                                      label: Expanded(
                                        child: Text(
                                          'Compass = ${indicatorData.compass?.toStringAsFixed(0)} degrees ',
                                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 27,
                                              letterSpacing: 2,
                                              color: Colors.black,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    )),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        oilTempText(),
                        Flexible(
                          fit: FlexFit.loose,
                          child: Container(
                              height: 60,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                                    colors: [
                                      Color.fromRGBO(10, 25, 123, 0.5),
                                      Color.fromRGBO(200, 200, 200, 0.5),
                                    ],
                                    begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                    end: Alignment.centerRight,
                                  ),
                                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                    Radius.circular(20.0),
                                  ),
                                  boxShadow: [
                                    BoxShadow(
                                      color: Colors.pink.withOpacity(0.2),
                                      spreadRadius: 4,
                                      blurRadius: 10,
                                      offset: Offset(0, 3),
                                    )
                                  ]),
                              child: stateData.water == 'null' ||
                                      stateData.water == '15'
                                  ? TextButton.icon(
                                      icon: Icon(Icons.water),
                                      onPressed: () {},
                                      label: Expanded(
                                        child: Text(
                                          'Not water-cooled / No data available!  ',
                                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 27,
                                              letterSpacing: 2,
                                              color: Colors.black,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  : TextButton.icon(
                                      icon: Icon(Icons.water),
                                      onPressed: () {},
                                      label: Expanded(
                                        child: Text(
                                          'Water Temp = ${stateData.water!} degrees  ',
                                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 27,
                                              letterSpacing: 2,
                                              color: Colors.black,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    )),
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
                  tooltip: isNotifOn
                      ? 'Toggle overheat notifier(On)'
                      : 'Toggle overheat notifier(Off)',
                  child: Icon(Icons.warning_amber_outlined),
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      isNotifOn = !isNotifOn;
                      print(isNotifOn);
                    });
                  }),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting stateData.oil in post frame callback. It means right after the widget building. Therefore your condition inside your build method is eventually null. You have to set it before build method has done.

For your second question. If you set new value to idData, value listenable builder already rebuild all the widgets. But i think you placed this widget to wrong location. If you move to parent and takes the conditions inside value listenable builder, probably your problem will be solved.

Comment: Thanks, the first issue is solved,
What about the second one? It is a widget method (A method with widgets inside it)
I have been playing around with my code, but it's not working properly,
I will update the OP with some more code and the location of my widget method.